# iOS passing data across multiple controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, segue

I am new to iOS app development.

I am now having several views like in the picture below (not exactly the case), in which I could get to the third view (rightmost) through 2 subsequent segues from the first view.

**EDIT: Supplementary Information:**
The third view is actually linked to a container in the second view. And it is a modal segue from the first to second.

[image]

And in the third view, I have a button which could bring me back to the first view by the `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` method. But how could I pass some data back to the first view?

I just know how to pass data between adjacent views using method like `prepareForSegue:sender:`. But I'm not sure how to do it across more than 1 view.

Should I use `Delegates` or `Singleton` or there are other better options?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to send data from third to first?

Comment: @AbubakrDar Yes, I would have to obtain some data from the third, and pass it back to the first, without going through the second one.

Comment: in this current situation i would think a delegate callback would be most appropriate, but a singleton can work as well if you need to keep the state of the system as a whole, really up to you, all depends on the problem

Comment: What kind of data? There may be different ways to design this.

Comment: You can take any of the given approach really, but avoid using _singleton for this purpose only.

Comment: @d.yuk, Let me know what approach you take!

Comment: @AbubakrDar i used delegates in the end

Comment: Ok, Thats a good one. Even more concise way is by Blocks.

Answer (score 1):

There are following ways for doing that.

- Delegates is one way to pass data back to your child.
- Blocks is another very simple approach.
- Notifications can also be used.
- Unwind segue is a new addition to this
- I would suggest Singleton at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to transfer some string .You can pass the data like this :

```
  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
   ViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vc"];
    controller.string = "some string";
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

If you want to right back to previous view controller then you can use completion handler :

```
  ViewController *vc = (ViewController*)self.presentingViewController;
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    vc.string = @"some string";
  }];
```

Answer (score 0):

See the correct answer of this question:

[Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

This question is been asked frequently, remember that you can also use an Unwind segue from the third to the first viewController and use :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"passDataFromThirdToFirst"]) {

 //Pass the data here with the methods that suggest 
 //in the correct answer I've linked you.
}  }
```